# Symbol look up Error for newly added function to existing C library

Tags: c

I downloaded the C library, wrote `test.c` to test the library. 
Compiled the library from src and created a static library (.a) file.
Then created my executable `test.exe` by linking with library successfully everything is fine.

Than i added my new fn in library - Declaration in hdr file, and definition in C file as usual. Rebuild the library, and re-created the executable again - no problem.

Now if i run the executable it shows - 
`symbol lookup error`  for any function i incrementally add in library. The error comes at run time.

Can somebody pls help, what could have gone wrong ? Its looks very trivial to add a new fn in existing library code.

Further, when i dump the library symbols using `nm <lib name>` , my newly added functions are showing up.

```
vm@vm:~/Documents/gdslCLibrary$ ./test.exe
Tree's size: 5
Element is found
Tree's element: 1
Tree's element: 2
Tree's element: 3
Tree's element: 4
Tree's element: 5
./test.exe: symbol lookup error: ./test.exe: undefined symbol: rbtree_next
vm@vm:~/Documents/gdslCLibrary$
```

Here `rbtree_next` is the new fn which i added.

Comment: Don't spam tags!

Comment: which tag i have spammed ?

Comment: Apparently the one I removed for you. Next time don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: To many possible errors. To exclude some: did you do a `make clean` before you rebuild the library? Have you switched on all warnings e.g.: `clang -Weverything ...` (although that is quite brutal) while re-building the library and re-building your own code? Do you use the library in that local folder or did you install it?